# why is the button for the about page not showing in the navbar?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, navbar

I am learning about ruby-on-rails , and setting up a user based web page . At the moment I am trying to add a default bootstrap navbar , but the right side button , which should be the button to the About page is not showing

I have tried to add the class="active" tu the  where the about button is , but still no success

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Saasapp</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
    family=Open+Sans:400,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data- 
    turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks- 
    track': 'reload' %>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" 
    role="navigation">
        <div class='container'>
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data- 
            toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">DevMatch</a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-nav- 
          collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
              <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>

    </nav>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Beacuse it is in your [`<head />`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp) tag and not in the [`<body />`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_body.asp)

Answer (score 0):

It is showing (as a regular link) on my test page.

If you want it to be a button add classes `btn btn-default`:

```html
<li><a class="btn btn-default" href="/about">About</a></li>
```

or in the Rails' way:

```rb
<li><%= link_to 'About', about_path, class: 'btn btn-default' %></li>
```